# capture overflow text height using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am using overflow:hidden property in the css which makes the text to be hidden when it goes outside the container.

can any one please let me know if there is a way to capture the height of the whole text including the overflow text

as well. height() value is just returning me the height of the container and not the overflow text ?

Comment: Can you include a jsfiddle

Comment: If you want to show text correctly use style={wordBreak: "break-all"}

Answer (score 3):

Use `scrollHeight`, see [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.scrollHeight).

```
$('#id')[0].scrollHeight
```

Answer (score 0):

[**Live demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Lg2v2/1/)

**JQuery**

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    $("#info").text("Width of real text: "+$('.real').css('width'));
    $("#info").html($("#info").html() + "<br/>Height of real text: "+$('.real').css('height'));

});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="overflow">
    <div class="real">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse non justo eget eros accumsan mattis. In a auctor magna, sit amet dapibus sapien. Mauris lectus justo, ornare eu pretium in, fringilla nec risus. Phasellus at risus dapibus, imperdiet tellus lacinia, feugiat risus. Nullam ultrices luctus ante, id aliquet eros. In iaculis elit ut hendrerit facilisis. Cras tristique non orci non sodales. Aliquam semper libero sed diam venenatis, imperdiet rhoncus augue eleifend. Nullam euismod mauris neque, ac semper erat posuere a. Nam a tortor commodo, adipiscing nisl vel, sollicitudin nisl. Suspendisse adipiscing laoreet neque sit amet tempor. 
    </div>
</div>

<div id="info"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.overflow{
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.real{
    width:300px;
}

#info{
    background-color:gray;
    margin-top:15px;
}
```

Comment: While I understand why this is working, some explanation as to why this works would be nice for the original poster